# Stop anchor link from scrolling on next page

Tags: html, anchor

I have a navbar with a drop down which has a series of links in the drop down. Each link in the drop down list links to the same page but a different tab on that page. So when you click on the link that takes you to tab 3, the 3rd tab appears automatically selected on that page. This is great, but the page automatically scrolls down a little bit to focus on that tab, so the page essentially jumps to that content. I understand this is how these #links work but is there a way to make the page not scroll down to that content but still select that tab?

Navigation:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href=http://website.com/page/tabbedpage#howitworks>How it Works</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href=http://website.com/page/tabbedpage#technology>Technology</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href=http://website.com/page/tabbedpage#application>Applications</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href=http://website.com/page/tabbedpage#savings>Savings</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is at the top of all pages to select the tab:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
   var activeTab = $('[href=' + location.hash + ']');
   activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can offset the position of the anchor tab.  I don't recommend inline styles, but an example would be:

```
<a name="howitworks" style="display: block; position: relative; top: -100px;"></a>
```

Of course, you would adjust the offset to match however much it scrolls down.

Comment: Instead of relative, make the position absolute.